# Missing image in cakephp blog post

Tags: mysql, cakephp, file-upload, upload, image-uploading

I am new to cakePHP and I am tring the blog example of cakePHP 1.3 book .
 I correctly upload  image in this blog example.The image name in database and image in DOCUMENT_ROOT/....correctly
but now I am wanted to show image in my blog with related post.

I am using this code for image upload...

```
 function add() {

if (!empty($this->data)) {
    if(isset($this->data["Image"]["image"]["name"])){
        $file = new File($this->data["Image"]["image"]["name"]);
        $ext = $file->ext();

        if ($ext != 'jpg' && $ext != 'jpeg' && $ext != 'gif' && $ext != 'png') {
 $this->Session->setFlash('You may only upload image files.');
        }else{
         if(move_uploaded_file($this->data["Image"]["image"]                ["tmp_name"],$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."test_om/blog/app/webroot/img/upload_image/"
                 . $this->data["Image"]["image"]["name"]) == true){
             $this->data["Post"]["image"] =  $this->data["Image"]["image"]["name"];
         }

    $this->Post->save($this->data);
    $this->Session->setFlash('Your post has been saved.');
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
                    }
    }
  }

 }
```

and i am showing image form this code

```
       <?php echo $this->Html->image('/img/upload_image/1.gif'); ?>
```

and this show same image with all post.
but i am wanted to set specfic image with its related post....

Comment: is your image being uploaded correctly? is it exists in path it should be?

Comment: yes,my image is uploaded correctly in this path folder and image name in database table, but now i am wanted to show this image on my blog with related post..plz help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure you are getting everything correct (in the database and the file where it should be) you should use something like this in the view.

```
<?php echo $this->Html->image($this->data['Post']['image']); ?>
```

this is assuming you are passing the data from the controller in the way described in the tutorial to a view view :)

if is an index view you should have a variable posts that have all post info, and in the view you will be in a loop like a foreach ($post as $post). Assuming this your view should have something like this:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->image($post['Post']['image']); ?>
```

Suggestion: use debug kit (cakephp plugin) so you can see what variables are passed down and the structure (like a pr($variable))

Hope all this helps you, if not, comment this post so i can try to extend my answer if needed

Comment: i use your code with image address just like....<?php echo $this->Html->image('/img/upload_image/'.$post['Post']    ['image']); ?> and its working correct...thanks for you help.

Comment: and is it possible to delete the image from saved folder if i delete the same post...

Comment: to delete an image from saved folder you have to do it php style or if you wan it cake style you may use the [file class](http://api13.cakephp.org/class/file)

Comment: i done it with         if(isset($path)){
                    unlink($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."test_om/blog/app/webroot/img/upload_image/".$path);
                }